Cannot able to Upgrade my dfx version. I have tried all well known command to ugrade but it is not working
My current dfx version is 0.9.3 but I want to upgrade it to 0.12.1 or higher but I failed to upgrade it. I used this command on wsl termnal DFX_VERSION=0.12.1 sh -ci "$(curl -fsSL https://smartcontracts.org/install.sh)" It did showed that it installed sucessfully but when I checked the dfx.json file and command dfx --version. It is showing 0.9.3 instead of 0.12.1. Do anybody have a solution for this problem?
I want to upgrade my dfx version to 0.12.1.

You should change your default dfx version by simply write:
dfxvm default <version>

In this case, it should be:
dfxvm default 0.12.1

